# Prove that this function is Riemann-Integrable?

Tags: real-analysis, proof-verification

Consider the following (discontinuous) function
$$
f(x) = \cases{1 \text{ if } x \neq 1 \\ 2 \text{ if } x = 1}
$$

I am attempting to show that $\int_{0}^{2} f(x) dx$ is Riemann integrable.

To do this, I have tried using dissections of width $\frac{2}{n}$ given by
$$
D_{n} = \left\{ 0, \frac{2}{n}, \frac{4}{n}, ..., \frac{2(n-1)}{n}, 2 \right\}
$$

So our upper Riemann sum is given by
$$
U_{D_{n}} = (n-1) \left( 1 \cdot \frac{2}{n} \right) + \left( 2 \cdot \frac{2}{n} \right)
$$

And our lower Riemann sum is given by
$$
L_{D_{n}} = n \left( 1 \cdot \frac{2}{n} \right) 
$$

Clearly $U_{D_{n}} \rightarrow 2$ and $U_{D_{n}} \rightarrow 2$, so the integral must be equal to 2.

However, I feel like this became insufficient as a proof when I defined $U_{D_{n}}$ and $L_{D_{n}}$. Can anyone explain how I can attempt to prove this rigorously?

Comment: So you are required to give an explicit and constructive proof for this case? There is of course the general result the the Riemann Integral will work on generally continuous functions, in the sense that the number of discontinuities is finite.

Comment: Are your cases right?  Do you want $x\not=1$ or $x=2$?  Don't you want the same point for both?

Comment: Your second sentence should be "I am attempting to show that $f$ is Riemann integrable on $[0,2].$"

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the original function was meant to be
$$
f(x)=\begin{cases}1&x\not=1\\2&x=1\end{cases}.
$$
As currently written the definition is not a function because $x=2$ has two values.

You just want to extend your construction to arbitrary partitions for a general proof.  Let $P_n$ be a partition of $[0,2]$ into $n$ intervals.  Let $X_n$ be the interval containing $1$.  Then,

- the upper sum is $2w(X_n)+\sum_{X\in P_n\setminus\{X_n\}}1w(X)=2w(X_n)+1(2-w(X_n))=2+w(X_n).$
- the lower sum is $1w(X_n)+\sum_{X\in P_n\setminus\{X_n\}}1w(X)=w(X_n)+1(2-w(X_n))=2.$

If you let the maximum size of an interval in the partition go to zero, then the limits converge to $2$.